# Tkinter image on canvas results in error message

Tags: python, image, canvas, tkinter

I have read all the posts about how to save your image so it is not garbage collected. So in the code below I have done so by adding self.mapimage.image = self.map.  This works, but I get this callback error: 
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'image'.  The program continues to work after this error. Any help from the Tkinter experts of the world would be greatly appreciated.

class OpenClose:

```
def __init__(self, pullcat, pullitem):

    self.pullcat = pullcat
    self.pullitem = pullitem

def openfile(self):
    if self.pullitem == 'Watershed':
        self.watfile = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes = (("Watershed Files", "*.wshed"), ("All files", "*.*")))
    elif self.pullitem == 'Devices':
        self.devfile = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes = (("Devices", "*.dev"), ("All files", "*.*")))
    elif self.pullitem == 'ModelSettings':
        self.setfile = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes = (("Settings", "*.set"), ("All files", "*.*")))
    elif self.pullitem == 'Map':
        self.mapfile = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes = (("Map", "*.gif"), ("All files", "*.*")))
        self.map = PhotoImage(file = self.mapfile)
        self.mapimage = guiset.getcanob().create_image(640,480, image = self.map)
        self.mapimage.image = self.map
```

Comment: Why do you think `self.mapimage` has an attribute named `image`?

Comment: Bryan, thanks for answering. I am going by the link below, which I now see you posted about 2 years ago.  If take out the last line of code, the image does not appear.  Any suggestions would be great. http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-do-my-tkinter-images-not-appear.htm

Answer (score 1):

`create_image` returns an int that serves as an identifier for the canvas image.  You need a different reference to the image.  The line

```
self.map = PhotoImage(file = self.mapfile)
```

is sufficient.  It gives you a permanent reference to the image, so it won't be garbage-collected.  Just delete the line

```
self.mapimage.image = self.map
```

and you ought to be okay.  (If you just had `map` instead of `self.map` that would be a local variable which would go out of scope when `openfile` completed, and your image would be garbage collected.  But since `self.map` is an attribute of you `OpenClose` you will have a reference to the image until the object is destroyed.)